# Is Web API suitable as services for IoT?

Tags: web-api, high-performance, iot

The issue I care about here is high throughput, there are a lot of sensors (monitoring devices) which send data to the server at high frequency.

It looks really like that we have to use `UDP` protocol for such kind of data transfer. However I've never used `UDP` for high-level logic API programming, a Web API using http would be easier.

Could you please suggest anything suitable for this?

Comment: Receiving and handling UDP packets is actually not that hard. However, without knowing the various parameters of your problem it's difficult to say whether this is the right approach. Perhaps you should give a bit more detail such as kind and number of sensors, actual frequency of measurements, data storage and processing requirements etc.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner I know it's not hard but it's not widely supported and looks like we have to deal with low-level programming (with socket). still it's inconvenient compared to http. Our system (with sensors, servers...) is actually small at first (and I'm sure with this initial size, web api is fine) but in future it will grow unlimitedly so I need a good solution first that can help it scale up fine. The back-end should look just like a back-end behind a typical Web API with Oracle server, api gate way for various kinds of client apps (which consume the sensors' data)

Comment: IoT is a pretty broad (mmh... marketing ?) term. This really depends on your specific application. In addition to @HansMartinMosner's criteria, are you concerned about reliability? What's the expected network coverage? Can you tolerate delays? Inconsistent data? Is battery usage a problem? Do you need SSL/TLS?

Comment: @Tibo I'm talking about sensors only (the clients using mobile devices don't require high through-put or any intense data transfer). The only job they do is send raw data to the server and the server just need to save that raw data without processing anything. The reliability has the most priority and data can be failed to transfer for some very short time (under half a second). I'm not sure about the security for this communication channel (between sensors and servers) and actually I think it's not necessary, the communication here is one way from sensors to server.

Comment: What is "a lot" and what is "high frequency"

Comment: @whatsisname I think I stated it clearly about `a lot of sensors`. There are many sensors distributed around and connect to the servers via Internet. What I meant at high frequency are all the requests sent from the sensors to servers. Each sensor can send request (like blasting requests) to server at high frequency and so many sensors can increase the total throughput of requests to servers many more.

Comment: @Hopeless: no, you did not. "A lot" could mean a few thousand, or a few million. "High frequency" could mean one sample per few seconds, or sampling at several kHz. Where on the spectrum this application lies will significantly influence the constraints that need to be dealt with.

Comment: @whatsisname: so your question before really really confused me, you asked "what" but it should have been "how" or "more specifically".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP is a pretty heavy weight protocol.

- It has a limiting Request/Response style
- It is designed for the wide-scale and scaleable dissemination of data.
- It operates within a lossless and guaranteed data deliver protocol TCP (excepting the newer standards which optionally support other underlying mechanisms).

  - TCP is heavy weight as it requires a 3-way handshake prior to delivering any data. Depending on how the connection is managed this could preclude successful data-transfer or ensure a three-fold overhead.
  - TCP also enforces a 64 KB transfer window, if the network has significant round trip latency this will slow overall throughput.

Your particular IoT swarm might be composed of devices with the capacity for sustained HTTP communications. This is not without downsides: chiefly network and energy demands, but also the exclusion of less capable devices.

Additionally UDP packets are not terribly difficult to receive/send. A simple web search with "udp socket tutorial" shows up a number of resources that give high level understanding, and detailed language specific instructions.

There is a lot of flexibility in how you orchestrate a UDP protocol. How you do chose to orchestrate it depends largely on what sort of communication occurs between the device/server/peers. A good plan would be to imagine a sizeable heterogeneous swarm with a non-trivial network and consider how those devices/servers/peers communicate, and what that communication requires in order to be considered effective within the constraints of network and device.

Comment: thanks for the insight a bit into the protocols. As I understand your advice is go for UDP and not HTTP? Actually my original wonder is about the application of http in this field in reality. Looks like it can be used but we have to accept trade-off between performance and the coding convenience.

Comment: My recommendation is to analyse how the swarm of devices are going to communicate, and what they need to achieve. Then with that in mind pick the appropriate communication technology/technologies. It might just be the case that HTTP is the correct approach due to firewalls, scalability or some other concern, it might be one of several communication methods. It might be that UDP is more appropriate. My feeling is that HTTP is not the best solution or even the most reasonable solution (though it is *a* solution).